# How to get only the latest filename inside the directory

Tags: java, linux

My requirement is to ssh to a linux box and then traverse to a directory and get the latest file's name all through Java code.

I am stuck at retrieving the latest file name. Here is what I am using

```
ls -ltr /abc/dir/sub_dir|tail -n 1|cut -d' ' -f 11
```

But this does not work all the times.
Usually on doing ls -ltr on a directory, the output will be something like the below pattern.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 xyz users   2070 May 27 20:16 9ZVU8ZNLL.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 xyz users   1507 May 28 02:29 VU8ZNLL.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 xyz users   1507 May 28 13:59 U8ZNLL.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 xyz users    944 May 28 14:46 Q9ZVU8ZNLL.xml
```

Using the above utility sometimes I get the file name and sometimes I get the date or timestamp or a null value which causes problem in my further processing.
What is the best way to get ONLY the latest file name.

Comment: what's the reason for [java] tag?

Answer (score 1):

This should work but it will break if your filenames have spaces in them.

```
ls -ltr | tail -n 1 | awk '{ print $NF }'
```

As **@EricJablow** stated in the comments, you can by-pass `-l` option and skip `awk` altogether.

```
ls -tr | tail -n 1
```

Comment: This shows all the filenames inside the directory. I want only the latest one.

Comment: Thanks! Can you also briefly tell what '{ print $NF }' does

Comment: `{ print $NF }` will print the last column. The reason I said that it will break in filenames with spaces is if there is a filename called `help me.txt`. `$NF` will become `me.txt` since `awk` by default splits the line on space.

Comment: You don't need the `-l` option, and then you don't need `awk`.  Just `ls -tr | tail -n 1` should work.  However, if the original poster wants only regular files, the solution using `find` would be better.

Comment: Your updated solution is straight forward and is probably enough here. As Eric Jablow stated, using "find" provides more options (eg. scan subdirectories, pattern matching).

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the Java program on the remote machine, or are you running locally and trying to invoke ssh from it?  If you want a local program that invokes ssh somehow to run commands on the remote machine, look at the jSch library from JCraft. Here is an [example by Ayberk Cansever](http://canseverayberk.blogspot.com/2011/10/ssh-client-connection-example-with.html). You can use the UNIX pipelines other people have given instead of the command in the example.

If you are invoking ssh and trying to run a Java file on the remote machine, I  would guess that the point of the assignment isn't to invoke a shell from your Java program, but to use the capabilities of the Java 7 `Files` object or its predecessors in earlier Java versions.  Look at `Files.readAttributes()`, `Files.walkFileTree()`, and `Files.getLastModifiedTime()`. This seems unlikely, because Java buys you nothing in this case.

Comment: I am running from a remote machine. 
Also like you suggested in one of the answer, I think `ls -tr|tail -n 1`       gives the latest file created with stuff like permissions,user group, timestamp. Since I need only the filename (no filenames to have spaces with them), I feel `ls -ltr | tail -n 1 | awk '{ print $NF }'` suits exactly.

Comment: `ls` with the `-t` option gives last modification time order, and `-r` reverses that.  If you are running from a terminal, you might have created an alias for `ls` to add default options: `alias ls="ls -F"` for example adds sigils for file types.  To avoid that, use `/bin/ls -tr | tail -n 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar use case: find the newest folder matching a pattern "foo" in a directory. The same thing can easily be adapted to find any file.

Try:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name "*" -type f -printf '%f\n' | xargs ls -d --sort=time | head -1

find "." ... directory path
-name "*" ... pattern match
-type f ... only find files, no directories
```

The result is converted, sorted by time and the newest element is returned.